# Livesuit and SP Flashtool

Tags: usb, 15.10, android

When using Livesuit and SP Flashtool on Ubuntu 15.10 64bit I am facing an issue when connecting USB device: The device connects for a while and immediately disconnects.

Dmesg output:

```
[ 8122.616522] usb 3-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 8122.710680] usb 3-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2000
[ 8122.710686] usb 3-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 8122.710690] usb 3-1.2: Product: MT65xx Preloader
[ 8122.710692] usb 3-1.2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[ 8125.260305] usb 3-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
```

Comment: Have you installed `ibusb-dev`?

Comment: I think yes. It was a requirement of Livesuit. The trouble I was encountering that the hardware is being disconnected after a short while.  I can confirm this soonest on Friday.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm, the libusb-1.0-0-dev is installed on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I have found the problem. I had blacklisted before the `cdc_acm` driver which is necessary for the SP Flashtool to work. So I enabled the `cdc_acm` driver by deleting the entry in the 
`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.